# coffeescript extend class constructor

Tags: oop, coffeescript

```
 class RedGuy
       constructor : (@name) ->
           @nameElem = $ @name
           @nameElem.css color : red

 class WideRedGuy extends RedGuy
       constructor : ->
           @nameElem.css width : 900

 jeff = new WideRedGuy '#jeff'
```

I would like `#jeff` to be both red and wide, but I always get `this.name is undefined`. How can I extend the constructor (append?) so that I have access to the properties of the original object?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to explicitly call `super` for this to work. Calling `super` in `WideRedGuy` will call `RedGuy`'s constructor, after which `@nameElem` will be properly defined. For a more in-depth explanation, you should consult [coffeescript's documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) on the matter.

```
class RedGuy
      constructor : (@name) ->
          @nameElem = $ @name
          @nameElem.css color : red

class WideRedGuy extends RedGuy
      constructor : ->
          ## This line should fix it
          super # This is a lot like calling `RedGuy.apply this, arguments`
          @nameElem.css width : 900

jeff = new WideRedGuy '#jeff'
```

Comment: OMG, I'd been struggling to understand `super` and now I completely understand. Thank you so much!